How to set the revision values(e.g.Rev.1) using itext5
Suppose I have signed pdf that have 3 signs signed under rev1 now for the next sign its showing rev4 so I need to set it to rev2.
Tried to set the values to signature fields but didnt work.And couldnt see any revision related object is getting added or updated while signing process

These revision numbers or names you see in the signature panels of Adobe Acrobat or the Foxit PDF Reader are not given by the PDF, they are determined by the PDF viewers themselves.
Adobe Acrobat uses the number of previous signature fields in that process resulting in the revision after the initial revision with 3 signatures being revision 4
Thus, the only way to make those revision identifiers consecutive currently is to refrain from adding multiple signed signature fields in the same revision.
